# mssql python Connection

Tags: python, sql-server

I am using Pycharm and try to link to a mssql server. When I link to a server that requires SQL authentication, the connect is created successfully. However, when I try to link to a server that requires my Windows Authentication, even though I use my username or password of windows log in, I cannot connect successfully. May I know what should be a proper way to setup if it is windows authentication.

I am using the below code:

```
import pymssql
conn=pymssql.connect(host="10.xx.xx.xx",user="CORPORATE/mywindowsloginname",password="mypassword",database="BIC_reference")
cur=conn.cursor()y
cur.execute('SELECT top 10 * FROM dbo.hi_invoiceline')
print (cur.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to use Windows Authentication you have to add the property  `trusted_connection='yes'` to your connection string. In this case you can omit user and password:

```
conn=pymssql.connect(host="10.xx.xx.xx",database="BIC_reference",trusted_connection='yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Windows Authentication, you should not specify any user credentials. The following should work assuming your Windows account has the relevant permissions:

```
conn=pymssql.connect(host="10.xx.xx.xx",database="BIC_reference")
```

I have tested this using `pymssql-2.1.3`. Using this version there was no need to specify `trusted_connection='yes'` (see apomene's answer), however, you may want to try that as well in case the above snippet doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Jaco, thanks so much for your answer. I am using pymssql-2.1.3, however, and try both with or without the property, it still doesn't work. May i know how to check what's wrong with that? Error message i got is

Comment: The error message is missing in your comment. Has Windows authentication been enabled on your SQL Server instance ?

Comment: File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (10.22.141.56:1433)\n')